# Theme translates the_author_posts_link. How can I remove their translation?

Tags: themes, translation

My theme (Avada) translates the function `the_author_posts_link` to add “By ” before the author’s name (see their code below). I don't want “By ” before the author’s name. How can I override this without messing with the php file where this is given in the theme?

```
            if ( $settings['post_meta_author'] ) {
            ob_start();
            the_author_posts_link();
            $author_post_link = ob_get_clean();

            // Check if rich snippets are enabled.
            if ( fusion_library()->get_option( 'disable_date_rich_snippet_pages' ) && fusion_library()->get_option( 'disable_rich_snippet_author' ) ) {
                /* translators: The author. */
                $metadata .= sprintf( esc_html__( 'By %s', 'Avada' ), '<span class="vcard"><span class="fn">' . $author_post_link . '</span></span>' );
            } else {
                /* translators: The author. */
                $metadata .= sprintf( esc_html__( 'By %s', 'Avada' ), '<span>' . $author_post_link . '</span>' );
            }
            $metadata .= '<span class="fusion-inline-sep">|</span>';
        } else { // If author meta data won't be visible, render just the invisible author rich snippet.
            $author .= fusion_render_rich_snippets_for_pages( false, true, false );
        }
```

Comment: Best bet would be to reach out to Avada for this.  Are you using a child theme?

Comment: You could edit the translation files with poedit or something which does the same job.

Comment: @ArgGeo I'm not familiar with that, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @TonyDjukic I am using a child theme. Avada will only help if I pay, so I'm trying to sort this out myself first.

Comment: Inside your theme's folder (Avada) there should be a folder called "translations", "languages" or something similar. There you will find .po and .mo files for several languages. You should probably edit the EN version. You can download https://poedit.net/, open the .po file and search for "By" then replace it with the desired text (maybe leave it blank?). Save it and replace the file in the theme folder.

Comment: Don't you have to pay to use Avada anyway?  I thought it was a commercial/licensed theme?

Comment: @ArgGeo would that not catch “By ” anywhere on the site, even in the middle of an article, etc.? as opposed to a targeted removal of “By ” just in the author link function?

Comment: @TonyDjukic my support expired and I'm not keen on paying for another 6 months of support for little things like this.

Comment: Can you search the Avada theme files and locate the template_tag that generates the “byline”?  It’ll be somehow associated with entry_meta or “posted_on”. As a guess.  From there we can recreate it and try to replace it.

Comment: "By" will be available in the .po file as many times as it appears in the theme's templates. If it is used in 2 places then you will find it 2 times in the .po file. Not sure which one is the correct? Try changing them one by one and check which one is right. Also, .po files are only related to the theme's templates, not your content so do not worry about messing up your content.

Comment: Do you really need author bio there? If you cannot get support from developers I'd remove if using "fusion-meta-info-wrapper {display: none;}" in the custom css and consider a third party plugin to provide author details. It's not necessarily a good answer but it's a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @ArgGeo. I'm not too familiar with the approach you're recommending, but I'll put some time into it and see if I can sort it out.

Comment: @TonyDjukic, I've used the String Locator plugin for wordpress and the only place I've found this in the theme's files is in the code I shared above. Their template php files (for posts, pages, etc.) point to a function in /includes/lib/inc/functions.php which then determines how to display the metadata. So the code I shared above is all there is to work with as far as I can tell.

Comment: My workaround for the moment, has been to delete this `echo avada_render_post_metadata( 'single' );` from the single.php file, which stops Avada from using the above function to display the metadata, and then I wrote my own custom code in my child theme's functions.php file to display the metadata the way I want, and added an echo to that in single.php and other template files. But that's not ideal as it removes much of the functionality around metadata that comes with the theme. I still think a better option would be to find a way to eliminate “By” somehow and still use their theme functions.